# Quartz : Triggers tables insertion method

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I'm now working with Qrtz and found many times that the child jobs were not fired automatically after the mother job already executed. I've investigated the log which generated by log4j in the QRTZ library. We found that there was a trigger missing problem from the table "qrtz_simple_triggers". The problem occurred since the Mother job did the trigger insertion into table "qrtz_triggers" and then it should insert the data into "qrtz_simple_triggers" Immediately. But for my case, there was a period delayed about 1 sec during the simeple trigger completely inserted into the table and in the same moment, there was an operation from the Thread pooling to UPDATE the trigger status in table "qrtz_triggers" from "WAITING" to "ACQUIRE" as while as the mother job was not finished the trigger insertion into "qrtz_simple_triggers". So, the main thread cannot find the simple trigger in the table and then it was stopped working. (For that child job)

My point is how to prevent the case like this? I think that the two insert statements are not in the same trasaction. I'm now investigation on that and suppose the solution to merge those statements into the same transaction. Would you bring me more ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Stop :)

Comment: How transactions are managed in your application , are you using spring to manage transaction?

Comment: Yes Blob, but I'm not sure how the QRTZ manage their database connections. Is there set an auto-commit for each connections which opened for the working jobs. I also investigating for this.

Comment: FYI, i'm using QRTZ ver. 1.8.6 :)

Comment: I just see this Q/A in the QRTZ official webpage.

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/faq
The last topic

Is this will shoot my trouble? I'm now trying this :)

Comment: Another question, should the connection management in quartz configured by the autoCommit = true ?

I try many ways to override the autoCommit by the properties file but got failed. There is no changes. I found only one way to force the QRTZ to disable autoCommit is to set the connection.autoCommit(false) directly to the QRTZ sources. Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Hi Sathapanic Sriprom, 
I faced the similar issue, but now I am not able to re-produce the same issue again. Can you please help me with the steps, how to re-produce this issue at local environment ?
  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring to manage transactions, then check [post](http://dhananjaypatkar.blogspot.in/2008/09/its-been-after-long-time-i-got-chance.html)

Setting

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore
```

Comment: Hi Blob, thanks a lot for you answer. This still not works for me :(

Comment: Are there any ways to force the QRTZ by using autoCommit = false?
As I've produced by modify the source code in QRTZ JAR and then repack it again into my project. It seems like that there need to setting by the code in QRTZ. Not works for the properties.